# How to prove the injectivity of $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) := \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: analysis

How should I go about proving the injectivity of this function, with only  very limited knowledge of linear algebra and analysis?
$f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) := \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{x}$

I am not sure how I can do this. Starting with  $\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{x}$ and doing transformations until I reach $x = y$ has not been successful, because as far is I know the function would not be injective if the domain was $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Show that the function is strictly increasing on $(0,1)$. You can either take its derivative, or show that each of the two terms are separately increasing.